# Repeat/Autoreverse animations in iOS 13.x

Tags: swift, ios13, uiviewpropertyanimator

Previously in swift you could do this:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.25, curve: .easeIn) {
  UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(Float.infinity)
  UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
  let transform = CATransform3DIdentity
  let rotate = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 45, 1, 1, 0)
  self.ex.layer.transform = rotate
}
```

However, now there is a deprecation message on `UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount` and `UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses`. Does anybody know what they was replaced with? Am I still able to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, or do I have to go to something like `CABasicAnimation`?

Messages are:

> 'setAnimationRepeatCount' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the block-based animation API instead
>
> 'setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the block-based animation API instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .curveEaseIn, .repeat], animations: {
    let transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    let rotate = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 45, 1, 1, 0)
    self.ex.layer.transform = rotate
}, completion: nil)
```

For all the possible calls, you can check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate)

In addition, if you really needs the `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, it has a [similar init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648367-runningpropertyanimator):

```
 UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .curveEaseIn, .repeat], animations: {
    let transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    let rotate = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 45, 1, 1, 0)
    self.ex.layer.transform = rotate
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the `UIViewPropertyAnimator` method and have that same functionality, or is Apple changing it so that method can only be used for non-repeating animations?

Comment: Yes, the problem is the deprecated `setAnimationRepeatCount` and `setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses` functions from the `UIView`, Apple started putting those options in code blocks. Just edited the answer.

Comment: Just for anyone else, the UIViewPropertyAnimator API ignores the .autoreverse and .repeat options

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me.. Using .repeat for the UIViewPropertyAnimator doesn't work.